# SOQL query: "sObject type 'FeedPollChoice' is not supported" for specific user

Tags: soql, permissions

I have an application that is making calls against the REST `/services/data/<api version>/query/` endpoint. My Salesforce org has two users: Alice has the "System Administrator" profile, and Bob is a "Partner App Subscription User". I am making queries of various object types as both Alice and Bob successfully.

The problem is when I query the `FeedPollChoice` object. My query is:

`SELECT Id,ChoiceBody,Position,FeedItemId FROM FeedPollChoice WHERE FeedItemId IN ('<feed_item_id_1>', '<feed_item_id_2>') ORDER BY Position`

This query works just fine when I run it as Alice. When I run it as Bob, I get this response:

`[{"message":"sObject type 'FeedPollChoice' is not supported.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}]`

Some further info:

- I first noticed this using API version 36.0 (I'm updating legacy software), but I can reproduce it with API version 46.0 as well.
- As mentioned, Bob is under the "Partner App Subscription User" profile, but this behavior is the same if I switch him to "Force.com - Free User" or "Work.com Only User".
- This is the only table I've been unable to query as Bob. I have successfully queried `FeedItem`, `UserFeed`, and some others.

My research suggests that Bob may not have a required permission to query this particular object, although I cannot find any settings related to it. Is there a specific permission I need to have to query this table, or is this being caused by something else entirely?